# Naming properties at compile time on generic class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to write a generic class, pass some types to it and then access it via properties.

I have written this code:

```
class Factory<T1, T2> where T1 : Test, new()
                      where T2 : Test, new()
{
    public T1 FirstType { get; set; }
    public T2 SecondType { get; set; }

    public Factory() 
    {
        FirstType = new T1();
        SecondType = new T2();
    }
}
```

and I'm using it like this (OtherTest implements Test):

```
Factory<Test, OtherTest> factory = new Factory<Test, OtherTest>();
factory.FirstType.MyMethod();
```

Then I can use FirstType and SecondType properties, however if I change the order:

```
Factory<OtherTest, Test> factory2 = new Factory<OtherTest, Test>();
```

This would have different behaviour, since FirstType would be OtherTest. I would like to pass instances and be able to write code like this:

```
Factory<Test, OtherTest> factory = new Factory<Test, OtherTest>();
factory.Test.MyMethod();    //I want to generate properties named after class
factory.OtherTest.MyMethod();
```

Can I do this in compile time?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is I'm afraid. Everything's fine up until "*I would like to pass instances and be able to write code like this ... Can I do this in compile time?*", and I'm afraid I've no idea what you're trying to do at compile-time.

Comment: I have a preety clear example. I want to create factory `Factory<A, B> factory = new Factory<A, B>();` and then access it fields by the name of the classes (A,B). I basically want to rename FirstType/SecondType to the type names of T1, T2 (A,B or Test,OtherTest).

Comment: Right. No, you cannot do that.

Comment: Not at compile time, no.

Comment: You might have a look at [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the property names through generic type parameters. The closest you can get is a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, Test> Tests;
```

Then you can use `typeof(T1).Name` and `nameof` to provide property names in a safe way.

```
Tests.Add(typeof(T1).Name, new T1());

Test test = Tests[nameof(FirstType)];
```

Comment: Is there really no way to wrap `Tests[nameof(FirstType)];` into something like `Tests.FirstType;` or `Tests.Get(FirstType);`?

Comment: @e.e There is not, as everyone so far has said. This is not something that C#'s generics support.

Comment: Well, you can use C#'s `dynamic` type and the [ExpandoObject Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8). But it resolves names a run time and is not type-safe.